# Webpack 5 Node Interface - can't resolve loader from node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm trying to compile custom TypeScript code in Node at runtime using Webpack 5.

It says it can't resolve ts-loader from node_modules because node_modules doesn't exist, except it definitely does exist (D:\Projects\projectCode\projectcode-server-test\node_modules).

**index.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { createFsFromVolume, Volume } = require('memfs');

const vol = Volume.fromJSON({
    './src/index.tsx': `
        console.log('index test');
    `
});

const inputFS = createFsFromVolume(vol);
const outputFS = createFsFromVolume( new Volume() );

const compiler = webpack(
    {
        entry: './src/index.tsx',
        mode: 'production',
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    use: 'ts-loader'
                }
            ]
        },
        resolve: {
          extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.js'],
        },
        output: {
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        }
    }
);

compiler.inputFileSystem = inputFS;
compiler.outputFileSystem = outputFS;

compiler.run((err, stats) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err.stack || err);

        if (err.details) console.error(err.details);

        return;
    }

    const info = stats.toJson();

    if (stats.hasErrors()) console.error(info.errors);

    if (stats.hasWarnings()) console.warn(info.warnings);
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "projectcode-server-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "memfs": "^3.2.2",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.2",
    "webpack": "^5.37.1"
  }
}
```

Here's the error from the log:

```
[   {
    loc: 'main',
    message: "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ts-loader' in 'D:\\Projects\\projectCode\\projectcode-server-test'",
    details: "resolve 'ts-loader' in 'D:\\Projects\\projectCode\\projectcode-server-test'\n" +
      '  Parsed request is a module\n' +
      '  No description file found in D:\\Projects\\projectCode\\projectcode-server-test or above\n' +
      '  resolve as module\n' +
      "    D:\\Projects\\projectCode\\projectcode-server-test\\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory\n" +
      "    D:\\Projects\\projectCode\\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory\n" +
      "    D:\\Projects\\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory\n" +
      "    D:\\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory",
    stack: "ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ts-loader' in 'D:\\Projects\\projectCode\\projectcode-server-test'\n" +
      '    at D:\\Projects\\projectCode\\projectcode-server-test\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\Compilation.js:1762:28\n'
+
      '    at D:\\Projects\\projectCode\\projectcode-server-test\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\NormalModuleFactory.js:730:13\n'
+
      '    at eval (eval at create (D:\\Projects\\projectCode\\projectcode-server-test\\node_modules\\tapable\\lib\\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:8:1)\n' +
      '    at D:\\Projects\\projectCode\\projectcode-server-test\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\NormalModuleFactory.js:273:22\n'
+
      '    at eval (eval at create (D:\\Projects\\projectCode\\projectcode-server-test\\node_modules\\tapable\\lib\\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:7:1)\n' +
      '    at D:\\Projects\\projectCode\\projectcode-server-test\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\NormalModuleFactory.js:488:15\n'
+
      '    at D:\\Projects\\projectCode\\projectcode-server-test\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\NormalModuleFactory.js:117:11\n'
+
      '    at D:\\Projects\\projectCode\\projectcode-server-test\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\NormalModuleFactory.js:571:8\n'
+
      '    at D:\\Projects\\projectCode\\projectcode-server-test\\node_modules\\neo-async\\async.js:2830:7\n'
+
      '    at done (D:\\Projects\\projectCode\\projectcode-server-test\\node_modules\\neo-async\\async.js:2925:13)' } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

It tried to resolve ts-loader from the inputFileSystem, which was overrided with memfs.

I had to instead override inputFileSystem with a union of memfs and the real fs, so that it could resolve ts-loader from the real fs. (I used unionfs).

Answer (score -2):

make sure that you have ts-loader installed

```
npm install -D ts-loader
```

and added to the rules

```
 module: {
    rules: [
      {test: /\.ts$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'ts-loader'}
    ]
  },
```

Comment: It is indeed installed and added to the rules, please take a look at the index.js and package.json I attached :)